# Slack AWS SQS Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, slack, slack-api

I want to connect a slack public channel within my team to SQS. I have used the SQS custom integration but I am not seeing any events. I can't find any way to debug the custom integration to work out what is going wrong.

Googling the slack documentation points to using the event API rather than custom integration. However the Event API will only let me send an event to a public URL without any security. For me to send to the SQS URL I need to use the AWS SDK to hash with the Access and secret keys. I don't see how I can use event API for an SQS integration.

Thus my question is should I be using custom integration or event API? If the former how do I debug it? If the latter how do I connect to AWS SQS?

Comment: I think you are confusing two different approaches to your problem. Either you use the existing Amazon SQS integration from the Slack App directory, or you build you own integration service, e.g. with the events API.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I used the existing Amazon SQS integration from the Slack App directory. I configured this with an SQS I created in us-east-1. I do not see anything coming through from Slack. I have tried to use the event API, but the configuration for that is just an URL, there isn't a way to set the access and secret for the SQS API. I know there are two approaches, but neitheer seems to work.

Comment: If you want help with your SQS integration, I would advise to post your configuration (but disguise the critical parts for security reasons) - otherwise it impossible to help you here. Or contact the SQS team directly.

Comment: Using the events API is a different approach. It would require you to develop your own integration app between Slack and SQS, which would include hosting the app on a public web server. The SQS credentials would have to included in your own Slack app, not be part of the event URL.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Thanks for confirming what I was assuming Erik. There are some gateway services out there but I don't want to use them as I have no confidence of end-to-end security of the slack messages. I was trying to avoid writing my own but... Cheers again.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of security level you need, but Slack will send messages via HTTPS Post to your app. So should be pretty secure.